# Floor of log equation $S=\left(\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor+1\right)x - \frac{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor+1}-10}{9}$

Tags: logarithms

I must find 'x' and I don't know how to solve the following equation.
Does it have a solution? How can I solve it?

$$
S=\left(\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor+1\right)x - \frac{10^{\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor+1}-10}{9}
$$

$$S,x\in\mathbb N$$

Comment: That \right+1) isn't going to work.

Comment: Also, an equation like $p(x)={\rm something\ in\ }x$ isn't meant to have a solution. Do you mean ${\rm something\ ib\ }x=0$?

Comment: @Gerry: I noticed that the \right was after instead of before the \rfloor (even if I didn't understand your message first... :-))

Comment: Note that, for positive integral $x$, $ \lfloor\log(x)\rfloor +1$ can be thought of as the number of digits of $x$ when written in the same base as the logarithm.

Comment: I must find 'x' for a given 'p(x)', exact or approximate value.

Comment: Carlos, if that's what you want, then that's what you should write in the question. Please edit.

Comment: If your $\log$ is in base $10$ (possible from Mark's remark) please specify it too...

Comment: Hey i dont know latex, so can i post a picture with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you could solve it by reasoning, here is my opinion.

If you can observe, the first part of S has and depends on log x to be a natural no. and the other one has (x-1)/9 as a term. Since both S and x are natural numbers, x can only be 1,10,100, 1000...

Answer (score 0):

For an integer $k\ge 0$, if $10^k \le x < 10^{k+1}$, then $\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor = k$ so
$$
S(x) = (k+1)x -\frac{10^{k+1}-10}{9}=(k+1)x-\frac{10}{9}(10^k-1)
$$
So, for example, if $1\le x \le 9$, then $S(x) = x$. If $10\le x \le 99$, then $S=2x-10$. If $100\le x\le 999$, then $S=3x-110$, and so on.

The first few $S$ values are
$$
\begin{array}
&x = & 1 & 2 &\dots & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & \dots & 99 & 100 & 101 & 102 & \dots 999\\ 
S = & 1 & 2 &\dots & 9 & 10 & 12 & 14 & \dots & 188 & 190 & 193 & 196 & \dots 2887\\
\end{array}
$$